# Adding file names from array in dataframe column in spark scala

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, hadoop

```
val hadoopConf = new Configuration()

val fs = FileSystem.get(hadoopConf)

val status = fs.listStatus(new Path("/home/Test/")).map(_.getPath().toString)

val df =  spark.read.format("json").load(status : _*)
```

How to add the file name in a new column in df?

I tried:

```
val dfWithCol = df.withColumn("filename",input_file_name())
```

But it adds the same file name in all the columns?
Can anyone suggest a better approach?

Comment: What is `input_file_name()`?

Answer (score 1):

It is expected behaviour because your json file having `more than one record` in it.

Spark adds the `filenames` for each record and you want to check all the unique filenames then do `distinct` on filename column

```
//to get unique filenames
df.select("filename").distinct().show()
```

**`Example:`**

```
#source data
hadoop fs -cat /user/shu/json/*.json
{"id":1,"name":"a"}
{"id":1,"name":"a"}
```

---

```
val hadoopConf = new Configuration()

val fs = FileSystem.get(hadoopConf)

val status = fs.listStatus(new Path("/user/shu/json")).map(_.getPath().toString)

val df =  spark.read.format("json").load(status : _*)

df.withColumn("filename",input_file_name()).show(false)

//unique filenames for each record
+---+----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |name|input                                                                       |
+---+----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |a   |hdfs://nn:8020/user/shu/json/i.json                                         |
|1  |a   |hdfs://nn:8020/user/shu/json/i1.json                                        |
+---+----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

in the above example you can see `unique filenames` for each record **`(as i have 1 record in each json file)`**.